# Why color doesn't changed for the turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I'm quite new to NetLogo and I want to use the below code to create a world of green and red circles, but the below code doesn't work with the color as it is only grey? any advice?

```
to create_turtles 
  ca  
   ask patches  [ sprout 1 ]
  ask turtles [ set shape "circle" set color green] 
end
```

[image]

Comment: code looks fine to me and I just copied it into a fresh model and it works. Is this exactly the code you are using? Also, I would recommend using a different procedure name, that is very close to the actual NetLogo primitive `create-turtles` so it would be easy to make mistakes that would be hard to spot.

Comment: yes I tried in a blank sheet and it works now thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code and it works just fine except it just create all green turtles (circles). If you want it red and green, I suggest you add some piece of code in the `ask turtles` command and may I suggest you to use the indentation style as well (usually NetLogo will do it automatically):

```
to create_turtles
  ca
  ask patches [ sprout 1 ]
  ask turtles
  [
    set shape "circle"
    set color green

    let chooser random 2
    ifelse chooser = 0
    [ set color green ]
    [ set color red ]
  ]
```

The `let` procedure is a local variable assigner and we let the value a random number of 0 and 1 (two numbers, hence the `random 2`, and primitive `random` always include 0 as first number).

In that example we ask the circles to randomly choose a number between 0 and 1. If it chooses 0 then it will set it color to green, otherwise red.

You can explore more about those primitives in the NetLogo Dictionary.

Comment: yes I tried in a blank sheet and it works now 
I will use this also to determine the red turtles 
Thanks a lot